# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given in RFE

Tags: python, rfe

```
rfe = RFE(lr,15)
rfe.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

im getting this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-10f06de816f9> in <module>()
      1 #Cut down number of features to 15 using automated approach
----> 2 rfe = RFE(lr,15)
      3 rfe.fit(X_train,y_train)

TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see this [document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html).

> RFE(estimator, *, n_features_to_select=None, step=1, verbose=0,
> importance_getter='auto')

so first attribute is mandatory. rest of the attributes are optional. so you have to mention optional attribute and pass the value. lets say **15** for **n_features_to_select** .

So, in that case it will be

> rfe = RFE(lr,n_features_to_select=15)

Comment: I think a better term in this context than "optional" is "keyword-only", since that's the cause of the error the questioner is having. The arguments are *also* optional, but that's not directly related to the exception. Anyway, +1 from me for linking the docs.

Answer (score -1):

try overriding with giving proper argument names, in your case i believe you want to enter the no. of features hence try this-

rfe = RFE(lr,n_features_to_select=15)